# Is there plugin support in JetBrains YouTrack?

Tags: plugins, youtrack

Can I install some plugins to extend it's basic functionality? As I see on the official site (https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/features/issue_tracking.html) there is no such possibility :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no plugin functionality indeed.